# Foreach Loop - Laravel - How do I seamlessly align multiple list-groups with different sizes on 3 columns

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to align some bootstrap list-groups next to each other on 3 columns. They should seamlessly align next to each other. Like in the picture:

[image: That's how I need it]

And that's how it is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypl5t.png)

As you can see, the list-groups do have different sizes. Now I've tried multiple things like give those list-groups a `float: left`

or give them a `col-md-4` but cause of the different sizes, sometimes some big gaps arise.

It would't be a problem if the data are static but I get them dynamically and print them out in my Laravel - foreach and I haven't got the result I want to have.

Does someone knows any css or javascript/jquery trick how I can do this? I don't want to give the boxes a specific height, I really want them like this so I gave them a `height: auto`

Thats my foreach loop:

```
<div class="list-group" style="text-align: center;">

        @foreach($category_groups['usergroups'] as $index => $group)

            <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="list-group-item height" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">{{ $group['name'] }}</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            {{ $group['description'] }}
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: {{ $group['age_min'] }}
                            - {{ $group['age_max'] }}</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: {{ $group['created_at']->format('d.m.Y') }}</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="{{ $group['link'] }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endforeach

    </div>
```

Thanks for any help and I apologize for my bad english!

Final renderes HTML ( Long code )

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;  text-align: center;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. 
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 17
                            - 21</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">dwadawdawdaw</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. 
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 1
                            - 2</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">test3test3</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            test3tes t3test3 test3test 3test3tes t3test3te st 3test3te st3test3test3t est3te est3test3test3test3tes t3test3tes3test3test3test3test3tes t3test3
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 15
                            - 20</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">test4test4</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            test3tes t3test3 test3test 3test3tes t3te
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 15
                            - 20</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">test5test5</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            test3tdwadaw
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 15
                            - 20</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">test6test6</h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            test3tdw adawtest3tdwa dawtest3tdwadawtest3tdw adawtest 3tdwadawtest3tdw adawtest3tdwada wtest3tdwadawt est3tdwadaw
test3tdwadaw test3tdwadaw test3tdwadaw test3tdwadaw
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 15
                            - 20</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 28.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <div class="list-group-item">

                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center big">  jsjsjsisijsjs </h4>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
                            sjsjsjsjsjsjsjs
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <span style="color: grey">Alter: 12
                            - 18</span><br>
                        <span style="color: grey">Erstellt: 29.06.2017</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Beitreten!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <br>
    </div>
    <style>
    .list-group-item {
        border-radius: 10px !important;
        min-height: 250px;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: both the images are same

Comment: yeah I'm trying to fix it

Comment: Okay works now, sorry for that!

Comment: Welcome to SO! And thank you for taking the time to post a well thought out question. I think you may be misunderstanding how the columns work in bootstrap . The problem is not with your Loop and Laravel so lets remove that from equation.  Can you post the final rendered html so we don't have to recreate it.

Comment: hey, sorry for my late answer. I've updated my question with some new code + changed the picture a bit up :) I want that that every list-group gets aligned like in the picture :) I posted some final rendered html code :)

Comment: with some css code ( just an height: auto + min-height )

Comment: I've tried something like array_chunk to my array but the result is the same like before...

Comment: Unfortunately bootstrap 3 is not equipped to handle "masonry" effect Bootstrap 3 is a "grid" based column system rows and columns. Flexbox may give you the solution you are looking for there are also some other [plugins](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dynamic-grid-with-salvattore-and-bootstrap-in-10-minutes--cms-20410) that may get what you need

Comment: Have a [look at this article](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/). It'll get you going in the right direction.